Did Mary know her baby was a sacrifice?
Luke 1:31-32:

"Behold, you will conceive in your womb and bear a son, and you shall name him Jesus.  He will be great and will be called Son of the Most High, and the Lord God will give him the throne of David his father."

When greeted by the angel Gabriel, Mary was told she would give birth to the son of God and that his kingdom would know no end. Mary was not written to have been told that her baby was destined to be crucified since before his birth. She unknowingly killed her son the moment she gave birth to him; her sole purpose was to give life to a baby so he could be killed in the name of everybody else. There was nothing she could do to save him from the very beginning; Jesus was born doomed by God.
If Mary was wholly unaware of the prophecy, did she know it wasn't her fault? She was responsible for Jesus as his mother, and from her perspective, he was killed under her care. Did Mary blame herself for her sons' death? I cannot understand the justification behind bringing so much pain to Mary for being the mother of the son of God.
Long story short, my question is whether or not Mary was aware of Jesus's destined crucifixion, and if not, why couldn't she know?

You say: "She unknowingly killed her son the moment she gave birth to him; her sole purpose was to give life to a baby so he could be killed in the name of everybody else. There was nothing she could do to save him from the very beginning; Jesus was born doomed by God." Please edit that out of your question because it is offensive to Christians. Also, apart from being inaccurate, we don't need or want personal opinions, either in questions or in answers.

By the standards and definitions appropriated by this question, then every woman must be censured for bringing a child into the world. For every human child will die, inevitably, because of sin. But there was a sacrifice instituted (in Israel) for the cleansing of childbirth. Which, by the way, Joseph and Mary made on behalf of the child Jesus. I agree with @Lesley that this question needs severe editing not to be offensive.

Yes, once she knew she would conceive of the Messiah. She knew Holy Scripture and its prophecies.

What did Mary know about how her child would die as a mature man? There is a highly significant episode recorded when she and Joseph took the infant, Jesus, to Jerusalem's temple, to be circumcised. The baby was just eight days old, as the Law prescribed.
There came to meet them an old man called Simeon who was:

"...just and devout, waiting for the consolation of Israel; and the
Holy Ghost was upon him. And it was revealed unto him by the Holy
Ghost that he should not see death, before he had seen the Lord's
Christ. And he came by the Spirit into the temple: and when the
parents brought in the child Jesus, to do for him after the custom of
the law, then took he him up in his arms, and blessed God, and said,
Lord, now lettest thou thy servant depart in peace, according to thy
word: For mine eyes have seen thy salvation." Luke 2:25-30 K.J.V.

Simeon then blessed the baby Jesus. He then directly addressed Mary, and this is where Mary first knew that suffering lay ahead, though she was spared any details:

"Behold, this child is set for the fall and rising again of many in
Israel; and for a sign which shall be spoken against; (Yea, a sword
shall pierce through thy own soul also,) that the thoughts of many
hearts may be revealed." (Ibid. vs. 34-35)

At that instant, a very elderly widow called Anna came in. She also blessed the Lord and began testifying about Jesus "to all them that looked for redemption in Jerusalem." (vs. 37-38)
The gospel accounts, and the Hebrew prophesies about Messiah, show that the whole point in Messiah living as a man on Earth, was to die as the only perfect sacrifice to God for sin that there ever has been. Yet not even Jesus' Apostles fully understood that until - after the crucifixion - he was resurrected from the dead, over 500 later witnessing him ascend bodily up into the sky, to return to Heaven, from where he promised he would later return.
Mary could not know either, until after she too witnessed that miracle, prior to which a symbolic sword did, indeed, pierce her heart as she saw Jesus dying on the cross. It all had to happen, according to God's plan of restoration, and Jesus agreed to leave Heaven to become the Word made flesh, born as a baby to the virgin Mary. At no point would she, or anyone else, ever think it was her "fault" that Jesus was crucified! And Jesus had reached the age of maturity by the time his 3 year ministry began. He was his own man - not his mummy's boy.
The short answer is, Mary knew suffering lay ahead, yet the outcome would be glorious, leading to salvation and redemption for both Jews and Gentiles, as Simeon and Anna told her.

In addition, when Jesus was missing for 3 days (Luke 2:46) , that can be taken as preparing Mary to miss him for 3 days between crucifixion and resurrection.

Did Mary know her baby was a sacrifice?
It is not completely known how much Mary actually knew about the future mission of her Divine Son Jesus as there are only glimpses of Biblical passages to aide us.
Obviously, the idea that Mary was simply in the dark about her Son’s identity and mission is obviously not true. Among other things, Mary knew not only



What she heard from Gabriel at the Annunciation (Luke 1:26–38), but also




what the angel told Joseph in his dream, presumably (Matthew 1:18–25);




What Elizabeth told Mary by the Holy Spirit at the Visitation (Luke 1:39–56);




What Gabriel told Zechariah about his own son John, presumably (Luke 1:5–23);




What the shepherds told Mary at the Nativity they heard from the heavenly host (Luke 2:8–20); and




What Simeon and Anna told Mary at the Presentation in the Temple (Luke 2:22–38).



Our Lord certainly knew his destiny, and even told his disciples in a veiled form.
How is it not possible that such a loving son, as Jesus would keep such secrets from his holy Mother Mary!!!
Mary knew that she was in store for sorrow as Simeon prophesied that a sword would pierce her heart so that the thoughts of many may be laid bared.
How many of us would have loved to hear the words between Mother and Son over the course of so many years?
